# Installing ROS on Raspbian

Tags: ros, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I am attempting to install ROS on Raspbian OS.

I know its meant for Ubuntu, but I've seen this done before and want to get a working installation on Raspbian due to some requirements I have.

When I try to `sudo apt update` though when following the `ROS Noetic` instructions on the website, I get `Err5: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bullseye Release   404    Not Found E: The repository http://packages.ros.org/ubuntu bullseye Release does not have a Release file. Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default. See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration`

However I'm more of a software developer than an OS exper, so Im not really sure where to even begin on debugging this, and searching some old threads didnt pull anything up for this issue that matched exactly with Bullseye, so Im not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This site is mainly for programming; see [help/on-topic]. Maybe try asking in [raspberrypi.se] or possibly in [unix.se].

Answer (score 1):

According to [REP 2000: ROS 2 Releases and Target Platforms](https://REP%202000:%20ROS%202%20Releases%20and%20Target%20Platforms) the system you are running on, *Debian Bullseye*, is listed as

*Tier 3 [s]*

described as

*" [s] " Compilation from source*.

This means you have to compile ROS for your distribution by your own. No binaries are distributed officially.

[Building ROS 2 on Linux](https://docs.ros.org/en/eloquent/Installation/Linux-Development-Setup.html) at the ROS docs describes the procedure to to it. Alternatively you could think about a docker as [ROS 2 on Raspberry Pi](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Installing-on-Raspberry-Pi.html) in the ROS docs describes. Last approach could be to use an unofficial build like [Ar-Ray-code/rpi-bullseye-ros2](https://github.com/Ar-Ray-code/rpi-bullseye-ros2) at GitHub.